# Carrusel de imágenes - jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un carrusel de imágenes que va cambiando de 4 imágenes y quisiera que fuera rotando de una imagen, por ejemplo que aparezca las primeras 4 imágenes pero a medida que fuera apareciendo el resto que fuera cambiando de a una imagen.

En mi código jQuery que anexe en el código no he podido hacerlo.

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar se lo agradecería, he intentado varias formas pero no lo he logrado.

A continuación envió las imágenes de como esta funcionando el carrusel  de imágenes actualmente.

Al cargar las primeras 4 imágenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando carga las otras imágenes si no tengo 4 imágenes mas como es el caso me esta dejando el carrusel vacío al lado derecho y se ve mal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<section class="cat-box scroll-box scroll-box-wide tie-cat-7">
   <h2 class="cat-box-title"><a href="posts\category\world\index.htm">Scrolling Box</a></h2>
   <div class="cat-box-content">
      <div class="group_items-box" id="wslideshow7">
         <div class="scroll-item">
            <div class="post-thumbnail">
               <a href="posts\48\index.htm" title="Permalink to Post With Featured Image" rel="bookmark">
               <img width="300" height="160" src="wp-content\uploads\2012\07\7413497016_9434c1917a_b-300x160.jpg" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt="Test 2" loading="lazy" srcset="wp-content\uploads\2012\07\7413497016_9434c1917a_b-300x160.jpg 300w, wp-content\uploads\2012\07\7413497016_9434c1917a_b-620x330.jpg 620w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"> </a>
            </div>
            <h3 class="post-box-title"><a href="posts\48\index.htm" title="Permalink to Post With Featured Image" rel="bookmark">Post With Featured Image</a></h3>
            <p class="post-meta">
               <span class="tie-date">July 30, 2012</span> 
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="scroll-item">
            <div class="post-thumbnail">
               <a href="posts\33\index.htm" title="Permalink to Post with SoundCloud" rel="bookmark">
               <img width="300" height="160" src="wp-content\uploads\2012\07\4088743235_690996beef_o-300x160.jpg" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy" srcset="wp-content\uploads\2012\07\4088743235_690996beef_o-300x160.jpg 300w, wp-content\uploads\2012\07\4088743235_690996beef_o-620x330.jpg 620w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"> </a>
            </div>
            <h3 class="post-box-title"><a href="posts\33\index.htm" title="Permalink to Post with SoundCloud" rel="bookmark">Post with SoundCloud</a></h3>
            <p class="post-meta">
               <span class="tie-date">July 30, 2012</span> 
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="scroll-item">
            <div class="post-thumbnail">
               <a href="posts\30\index.htm" title="Permalink to Post with Image + Lightbox" rel="bookmark">
               <img width="300" height="160" src="wp-content\uploads\2012\07\4756831209_cfe3227937_b-300x160.jpg" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy" srcset="wp-content\uploads\2012\07\4756831209_cfe3227937_b-300x160.jpg 300w, wp-content\uploads\2012\07\4756831209_cfe3227937_b-620x330.jpg 620w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"> </a>
            </div>
            <h3 class="post-box-title"><a href="posts\30\index.htm" title="Permalink to Post with Image + Lightbox" rel="bookmark">Post with Image + Lightbox</a></h3>
            <p class="post-meta">
               <span class="tie-date">July 30, 2012</span> 
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="scroll-item">
            <div class="post-thumbnail">
               <a href="posts\24\index.htm" title="Permalink to Post With Video" rel="bookmark">
               <img width="300" height="160" src="wp-content\uploads\2012\07\5709944739_578bc434a7_b-300x160.jpg" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy" srcset="wp-content\uploads\2012\07\5709944739_578bc434a7_b-300x160.jpg 300w, wp-content\uploads\2012\07\5709944739_578bc434a7_b-620x330.jpg 620w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"> </a>
            </div>
            <h3 class="post-box-title"><a href="posts\24\index.htm" title="Permalink to Post With Video" rel="bookmark">Post With Video</a></h3>
            <p class="post-meta">
               <span class="tie-date">July 30, 2012</span> 
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="scroll-item">
            <div class="post-thumbnail">
               <a href="posts\14\index.htm" title="Permalink to Maecenas mattis, tortor ut posuere aliquam" rel="bookmark">
               <img width="300" height="160" src="wp-content\uploads\2012\07\7543602860_c741e700c0_b-300x160.jpg" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy" srcset="wp-content\uploads\2012\07\7543602860_c741e700c0_b-300x160.jpg 300w, wp-content\uploads\2012\07\7543602860_c741e700c0_b-620x330.jpg 620w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"> </a>
            </div>
            <h3 class="post-box-title"><a href="posts\14\index.htm" title="Permalink to Maecenas mattis, tortor ut posuere aliquam" rel="bookmark">Maecenas mattis, tortor ut posuere aliquam</a></h3>
            <p class="post-meta">
               <span class="tie-date">July 28, 2012</span> 
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="scroll-item">
            <div class="post-thumbnail">
               <a href="posts\39\index.htm" title="Permalink to Elementum mauris aliquam ut" rel="bookmark">
               <img width="300" height="160" src="wp-content\uploads\2011\07\4148265552_7b438be4ab_b-300x160.jpg" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy" srcset="wp-content\uploads\2011\07\4148265552_7b438be4ab_b-300x160.jpg 300w, wp-content\uploads\2011\07\4148265552_7b438be4ab_b-620x330.jpg 620w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"> <span title="Not bad !" class="stars-large"><span style="width:72%"></span></span>
               </a>
            </div>
            <h3 class="post-box-title"><a href="posts\39\index.htm" title="Permalink to Elementum mauris aliquam ut" rel="bookmark">Elementum mauris aliquam ut</a></h3>
            <p class="post-meta">
               <span class="tie-date">July 30, 2011</span> 
            </p>
         </div>
        
         
         <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="scroll-nav"><a id="nextw7" href="#"><i class="tieicon-right-open"></i></a><a class="prev-scroll" id="prevw7" href="#"><i class="tieicon-left-open"></i></a></div>
   </div>
</section>
<!--<div class="clear"></div>-->
<!-- slider1 -->
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var vids = jQuery("#wslideshow7 .scroll-item");
    for(var i = 0; i < vids.length; i+=4) {
      vids.slice(i, i+4).wrapAll('<div class="group_items"></div>');
    }
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#wslideshow7').cycle({
            fx:     'scrollHorz',
            timeout: 3000,
            //pager:  '#nav7',
            slideExpr: '.group_items',
            prev:   '#prevw7',
            next:   '#nextw7',
            speed: 300,
            pause: true
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```